# How can I check if a foreign key has an attribute on its model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Product

```
class Product(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am at Product views.py, how can I check if an attribute exist in the 'Order' model?

What I'm trying to do is this ->

```
hasattr(Product, "order__name")
```

Comment: `if product.order and product.order.name`?

Comment: Why do you want to check if an attribute exists? You should know that: you have the `models.py` file, with the actual model. Do you mean to say: if the foreignkey is not null?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answers. Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough in the question. The problem is this one, I have two ForeignKey-s that have the same property. I want to access both of them using modelName__property. That's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the target model has a `name` attribute with:

```
hasattr(Product.order.field.related_model, 'name')
```

Here we thus access the `ForeignKey`, and obtain a reference to the model it targets, in this case the `Order` model, then we can check if that model has a `name` attribute.

It is rather odd that a `Product` however has a `ForeignKey` to an `Order`. Usually it is the other way around: an `Order` has many "`OrderLine`"s that then have a `ForeignKey` to the `Product` that these orderlines deal with.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answers. Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough in the question.
The problem is this one, I have two ForeignKey-s that have the same property. I want to access both of them using modelName__property. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: @EraKastrati: you access fields on a `ForeignKey` with `myproduct.order.name`, not `myproduct.order__name`.